# Purchasing Affinity designer on mac

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, imac, mac-appstore, design

If I purchase Affinity Designer on my iMac will I be able to use the app on my MacBook as well?
 I'd like to know if it works on one device or on any device that my iCloud account is signed into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac App Store apps can be used on any Mac signed in with your Apple ID.

> **Can I use apps from the Mac App Store on more than one computer?**
>
> Apps from the Mac App Store may be used on any Macs that you own or control for your personal use.

[Mac App Store: Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202152)